# common lisp implementation modify stack size at run-time

Tags: common-lisp

Are there any common lisp implementation that allow modifying the stack size at run-time? What about the size of the heap?

I am using sbcl and apparently these are defined when the executable is started, and cannot be altered afterwards.

Comment: What are you aiming to accomplish with this? The fact that you're fiddling with the stack dynamically is a bit odd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example ECL and LispWorks can extend the stack at runtime. One can see that both are also offering restarts when there is a stack overflow, to increase the stack size, if necessary:

**ECL**:

```
>  (defun s (n)
     (if (zerop n) 0 (+ 1 (s (1- n)))))

S

> (s 100000)

Condition of type: STACK-OVERFLOW
C-STACK overflow at size 4259840. Stack can probably be resized.

Available restarts:

1. (CONTINUE) Extend stack size
2. (RESTART-TOPLEVEL) Go back to Top-Level REPL.

Broken at S. In: #<process TOP-LEVEL>.
>>
```

See the ECL memory management documentation at: http://ecls.sourceforge.net/new-manual/re86.html

**LispWorks**:

```
CL-USER 31 > (s 1000)

Stack overflow (stack size 15997).
  1 (continue) Extend stack by 50%.
  2 Extend stack by 300%.
  3 (abort) Return to level 0.
  4 Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.
```

A variable in LispWorks allows customization: `SYSTEM:*STACK-OVERFLOW-BEHAVIOUR*`. See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/LW/html/lw-1440.htm#marker-887330 .

The *heap* grows automatically in most implementations by requesting more memory from the operating system. The next question then would be: can the heap shrink?

Comment: What about ccl? Out of curiosity, would it be hard to implement a dynamically resizable stack in sbcl?

Comment: @stackman: In CCL you can set the stack size of thread, if you start a new one. How hard is in to implement in SBCL? I have no idea. You would have to ask the implementors.